# How to use a user control on top of a menuItem in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, menuitem

I'm making various menus interfaces for a kinect, and i'm trying  a classical menu with menuitem control; to visualize the cursor i use a usercontrol handshaped (I need it, I can't use a custom cursor). I had problems with the child menuitem because them are not part of the main windows visualtree but I managed them.

The only thing that I can't fix is that when you open a menuitem he stays always on top of the other interface's elements, so it covers also my handshaped "cursor", because it is not a real cursor but only a "visualizer".

Do you have some tip on how to make always on top my user control, or change the behavior of the menuitem?

I add an image to show better the problem:
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VM7v.jpg)

This is an excerpt of the code: (the pseudocursor is defined in another in another file, and added by the canvas in the program)

```
<Window
    ....
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProvaHover"
    x:Class= "ProvaHover.MainWindow"
    Cursor="None"
    Title="MainWindow" WindowStyle = "None"  WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" SizeToContent="Manual" WindowState="Maximized" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ResizeMode="NoResize" Closed="Window_Closed">
<Grid x:Name="gridParent">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200" Name="row" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border BorderBrush="#FFA0A0A0" BorderThickness="1">
        <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Grid.Row="0"  Height="{Binding ElementName=row, Path=Height}"  FontSize="140"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  local:MagneticPropertyHolder.IsMagnetic ="True" Grid.ZIndex ="2">



            <MenuItem Header="_File" Name="fileMenu" Background="Transparent" local:MagneticPropertyHolder.IsMagnetic ="True" SubmenuOpened="filemenuitem_SubmenuOpened" Grid.ZIndex="2">

                <MenuItem Header="_New... " local:MagneticPropertyHolder.IsMagnetic ="True" Name="newMenu" Loaded="newmenuitem_Loaded" >
                    <MenuItem Header="_New... " Grid.ZIndex="2" />
                    <Separator />
                </MenuItem>

                <MenuItem Header="_Open..." Name="openMenu" local:MagneticPropertyHolder.IsMagnetic ="True" Loaded="openMenu_Loaded"  Grid.ZIndex="2"  >
                    <MenuItem Header="_New... " Grid.ZIndex="2" />
                </MenuItem>
                <Separator />


                <MenuItem Header="_Save" Name="saveMenu" local:MagneticPropertyHolder.IsMagnetic ="True" Loaded="savemenuitem_Loaded" Grid.ZIndex="2"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Save As..." Name="saveasMenu" local:MagneticPropertyHolder.IsMagnetic ="True" Loaded="saveasmenuitem_Loaded" Grid.ZIndex="2"/>
                <Separator  />

                <MenuItem Header="_Exit" Name="exitMenu" Click="MenuItem_Click" local:MagneticPropertyHolder.IsMagnetic ="True" Loaded="exitmenuitem_Loaded" Grid.ZIndex="2" />

            </MenuItem>

            <StackPanel Grid.ZIndex="2">
                <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="1" Margin="4" Stroke="#FFA0A0A0" Height="180" Fill="#FFA0A0A0"  />
            </StackPanel>



        </Menu>

    </Border>



    <k:KinectSensorChooserUI HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="sensorChooserUI"/>


    <Canvas Grid.RowSpan="2" x:Name="mouseCanvas" Grid.ZIndex="10" >

    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the z-order of the menu item by using its parent. The parent should have a collections property called controls from which you can call GetChildIndex and SetChildIndex methods.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I searched something about those 2 methods but it seems that they are under winforms, and I forget to say that I'm working with wpf

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't have as much experience with wpf but I believe there is a z index property or similar that you can use somewhere. Sorry I couldn't help you more.

Comment: I will make a check using the tip of Mark about ZIndex, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Most of the container objects that you have available are based off of the `Panel` container, it has an [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx) called [`ZIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex(v=vs.110).aspx) and  [`SetZIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.setzindex(v=vs.110).aspx) and `GetZIndex` methods .

Usage:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Name="Rect1" Grid.ZIndex="1"  Fill="Red"/>
    <Rectangle Name="Rect2"  Grid.ZIndex ="2"  Fill="blue"/>
    <Button  Grid.ZIndex ="3" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="207,225,0,0" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
</Grid>
```

This will set the ZIndex in the Xaml you can access it in your code behind by using the `Grid.SetZIndex` and `Grid.GetZIndex` Methods.

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Grid.GetZIndex(Rect1) == 1)
    {
        Grid.SetZIndex(Rect1, 2);
    }
    else
    {
        Grid.SetZIndex(Rect1, 1);
    }

    if (Grid.GetZIndex(Rect2) == 2)
    {
        Grid.SetZIndex(Rect2, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        Grid.SetZIndex(Rect2, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I found this property and I didn't really understand how it worked, so thaks for the explanation. I will try tomorrow and let you know, even if I suspect that this won't work, since the 2nd level menuitem (the one that appears in the popup) is not child of grid, and it belongs to another visual tree

Comment: even though it is in a separate visual tree, is that tree being added to a common container somewhere? This would be easier to come up with an answer if you could make a simple example that would duplicate your issue.

Comment: I've added the code and an image to better explain my issue